# CSS column-count selecting 1st and last column

Tags: html, css, selector, column-count

I've got a 2 column layout blog and i'm using the column-count css property, but the design requires that images and blockquotes in the first column to jut out to the left side (margin-left: -20px), and the 2nd column applies the same thing but on the right side (margin-right:-20px).

Is there a css selector for the 1st or last column? Is it possible to do that or would i have to try something else?

Comment: No, so far as I know there's no selector for specific columns in CSS as yet; the spec is here: "[CSS Multi-column Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)."

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get is using `td:first-child` and `td:last-child`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt9Lj/)

Example:

```
td { width:100px; height:50px; background:blue; }
td:first-child, td:last-child {
    background:red;
}
```

If for some reason you were wanting a specific column not on the outside you could use `td:nth-of-type(n)` or, if there are only `td` children, `td:nth-child(n)`, but this requires you know how many `td`s there are in the row. To do anything more specific you'd have to use javascript

Comment: the issue i have is that this is a responsive layout, where in mobile view i would have one column, and anything larger than that would be 2 columns. I'm using the column-count property to achieve this. 

Are there any other options besides tables or column-count?

Comment: There are other options, but that is the easiest way most likely. If you'd like you could share a demo with us and we could work with it